# Combining many log files in Amazon S3 and read in locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a log file being stored in Amazon S3 every 10 minutes. I am trying to access weeks and months worth of these log files and read it into python.

I have used boto to open and read every key and append all the logs together but it's way too slow. I am looking for an alternate solution to this. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality on Amazon S3 to combine or manipulate files.

I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to synchronize files to a local directory using the `aws s3 sync` command. This can copy files in parallel and supports multi-part transfer for large files.

Running that command regularly can bring down a copy of the files, then your app can combine the files rather quickly.

If you do this from an Amazon EC2 instance, there is no charge for data transfer. If you download to a computer via the Internet, then Data Transfer charges apply.

Comment: S3 event notification on object creation >> SQS Queue >> write a consumer for the queue and run it on EC2 => logs are staged automatically as soon as they're posted to the bucket, and can be manipulated/combined/filtered/recompressed/etc., either as soon as they arrive, or in batches.  This is also an excellent use case for EBS Cold Storage (sc1) volumes.

Comment: There is actually some functionality to combine files in S3 lurking in the MultiPartUpload API. Namely: [MultiPartUpload PartCopy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html). You can use that to merge existing objects (or byte ranges of objects) into a new object without the data ever leaving S3.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you're naive solution is probably only using a single connection and isn't making full use of your network bandwidth. You can try to roll your own multi-threading support, but it's probably better to experiment with existing clients that already do this (s4cmd, aws-cli, s3gof3r)

Once you're making full use of your bandwidth, there are then some further tricks you can use to boost your transfer speed to S3.

Tip 1 of this [SumoLogic article](https://www.sumologic.com/aws/s3/10-things-might-not-know-using-s3/) has some good info on these first two areas of optimization.

Also, note that [you'll need to modify your key layout if you hope to consistently get above 100 requests per second](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html).

Given a year's worth of this log file is only ~50k objects, a multi-connection client on a fast ec2 instance should be workable. However, if that's not cutting it, the next step up is to use EMR. For instance, you can use [S3DistCP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) to concatenate your log chunks into larger objects that should be faster to pull down. (Or see [this AWS Big Data blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/turning-amazon-emr-into-a-massive-amazon-s3-processing-engine-with-campanile/) for some crazy overengineering) Alternatively, you can do your log processing in EMR with something like [mrjob](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/).

Finally, there's also Amazon's new [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-athena-interactive-sql-queries-for-data-in-amazon-s3/) product that allows you to query data stored in S3 and may be appropriate for your needs.